# How show user friends in list of all people?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Oookay, editing question.

I'm using spring, hibernate and JSP.

SQL Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
  uuid              VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY                     NOT NULL,
  username          VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE                          NOT NULL,
  first_name        VARCHAR(255)                                NOT NULL,
  last_name         VARCHAR(255),
  middle_name       VARCHAR(255)
);



CREATE TABLE public.user_friends
(
  uuid          VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_uuid     VARCHAR(36) REFERENCES public.users (uuid) NOT NULL,
  friend_uuid   VARCHAR(36) REFERENCES public.users (uuid) NOT NULL,
  friendAddDate TIMESTAMP                                  NOT NULL,
  friendTypeId  INT                                        NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT friend_unique UNIQUE (user_uuid, friend_uuid)
);
```

Java Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    protected String uuid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    protected String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserFriend> userFriends = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_friends")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "user",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "friendUser",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_uuid")) })
public class UserFriend implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    protected String uuid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_uuid")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="friend_uuid")
    private User friendUser;

    @Column(name = "friendadddate")
    protected Date friendAddDate;

    @Column(name = "friendtypeid")
    protected int friendTypeId;
}
```

Now i'm making JSP page where i will show all users of system. So i have two sets:
Set - all users of system
and
Set - friends of current logged user.

I want to show on JSP all users and mark users who are friends of logged user.
And i want to ask: What best practice to do it?

Comment: Do you need help with the database schema? the ORM? The data structure? You question is very confusing.

Comment: This is a very broad question and essentially open to discussion, you need to rewrite it to show your code as to how you are doing it currently and then the community can provide you a better fix/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup some sort of flag in backend which would be used in your jsp page to determine the friends of current logged in user. If the flag is present mark the user, otherwise you proceed normally.

Comment: Some sort of flag where indeed? In model? In database? Or u re advice me to create new model for page?

Comment: Add a flag field in the POJO(beans) which you persist. Check for it on jsp page.

Comment: So, u want me create new field isFriend in class User and in for loop before send user to JSP check every user of all system is he a friend of logged user? That's your solution? I can make this for loop on JSP without extended field, but i think that it is bad solution for highload.

Comment: You'll have to do it somewhere. Or if you find other solution, do mention here.

Comment: i did not find other solution... only loop cycle